# Read all the values of a particular column of a file and store it in another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I have a `file.txt` which contains data like below:

```
col11 col12 col13 
col21 col22 col23
```

I fetch 2nd column of all the available rows (no. of rows may vary) using `awk '{print $2}' file.txt`

Now i need to append this result like below:

```
"Process 1" - col12
"Process 2" - col22
```

and so on for the number of rows fetched in `file.txt`.
How do i go about that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FNR` to get current line number:

```
awk '{print "\"Process " FNR "\" - " $2}' <in >out
```